# Какому источнику верить: Перси Биш Шелли или Перси Биши Шелли?

Tags: транскрипция

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Percy Bysshe Shelley - нужно ли взывать к точной транскрипции или есть традиция?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В таких случаях, как правило, коллективный разум Википедии не ошибается, а он рекомендует **Биш**. Такое произношение подчеркивается и в английском варианте энциклопедии.

Однако стоит учитывать, что метод транслитерации для английских имен и названий стали использовать сравнительно недавно. До этого действовало правило: как пишется, так и переводим. Отсюда Невтон (Newton), Ватсон (Watson) и т. п. Отсюда же транскрипция *Биши*, так что ошибкой она тоже не будет. Справедливости ради скажем: и сами англичане иногда путаются в произношении подобных имён.